# How to use groovy style in IntelliJ IDEA 2016 Watches?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I've tried to use Groovy expressions when debugging Java code in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Community Edition.

The description from [Jetbrains](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/03/intellij-idea-2016-1-is-here/) provides the picture where it is possible to choose Groovy/Java.

[image: The picture from Jetbrains]

However I can't get, how to use it. My IDEA 2016.1 Community Edition looks like in the picture below.

[image: My IntelliJ IDEA 16.1]

**Edit**:
I have groovy installed and I can use groovy Watches there.
[image]

Comment: Do you have groovy installed?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes, I had groovy installed, see updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add groovy lib to the module dependencies.
There's a request to skip this step in future: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153186

Comment: Added groovy-2.4.6.jar to the IDEA module dependencies. It works like a charm.

Comment: @ФимаГирин: Where can I add the dependency when using gradle? I have tried to add: `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.6' }` to my build.gradle file but without any success.

Comment: @AustrianDude: please, try 
    `dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    }`

Comment: @AustrianDude: Make sure in the Project Structure (`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S`) there is necessary dependency: `Gradle: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11`

Comment: @ФимаГирин: Thanks I try to get it running today :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you specify language when you create / edit watch. I.e if you try to modify existing watch or add a new one, you should see language selection icon to the left of expression.

So, if you use "add to watches" from context menu, this selection is skipped.